# Get an @Input() value from the child code returns undefined

Tags: angular, angular6

I can't use a value given by a parent in a child component code. I don't understand why...
In my parent HTML, I set a component app-courses-array with a hashtag value (value1)

```
<app-courses-array [eventHashtag]="value1"></app-courses-array>
```

My child HTML is working and the event hashtag is well displayed.

```
<div class="panel-heading">
      Hashtag received {{ eventHashtag }}
</div>
```

But when I try to get it in my child component code (to do something else with it), I just get an "undefined" :

```
export class CoursesArrayComponent {

   @Input() eventHashtag: string;

   constructor() {
       console.log("Value of hashtag", this.eventHashtag);
       // this displays "Value of hashtag undefined" on the console
   }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: If you want to pass a string value, remove the square brackets, otherwise its looking for a variable called `value1`

Comment: That value isn't going to be available in the constructor. Look into the lifecycle hooks, OnInit and OnChanges most likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usual, the Input property isn't initialized until view is set up.You can access your data in ngOnInit method.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.eventHashtag); 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

are you retrieving this `value1` data via a get request or something? If so it may be because the component gets loaded before the `value1` data has been received. To counter this you can add an *ngIf to app-courses-array like so:

```
<app-courses-array *ngIf="value1" [eventHashtag]="value1"></app-courses-array>
```

now the component will only be loaded once the value1 data is not undefined. (undefined equals false)

Here's a link that explains the difference between constructor and ngOninit and can also explain why your variable appears undefined: https://toddmotto.com/angular-constructor-ngoninit-lifecycle-hook In short, the constructor is part of ECMA6(javascript) not angular. It is used to initialize regular variables in its body but you can also use it to inject angular components into the class by declaring the it as a constructor argument

Answer (score 0):

It won't be available in the `constructor`. It will be available in `ngOnChanges`. That's the method that gets called when the `@Input` properties on a Component change.

Try logging it in the

```
ngOnChanges() {
    console.log(this.eventHashtag); 
}
```

Also, implement the `OnChanges` lifecycle hook that Angular provides. You might want to import it from `@angular/core`

```
import { Component, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
```